# error 403 Forbidden running bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_price

Tags: magento2, product-reindexing

On Magento 2.3.4 from the console I can run all reindex and

**running**

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_price
```

**error**

```
>     Product Price index <!DOCTYPE html> <html style="height:100%"> <head> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
> initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" /> <title> 403 Forbidden
> </title></head> <body style="color: #444; margin:0;font: normal
> 14px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; height:100%; background-color:
> #fff;"> <div style="height:auto; min-height:100%; ">     <div style="text-align: center; width:800px; margin-left: -400px;
> position:absolute; top: 30%; left:50%;">
>         <h1 style="margin:0; font-size:150px; line-height:150px; font-weight:bold;">403</h1> <h2 style="margin-top:20px;font-size:
> 30px;">Forbidden </h2> <p>Access to this resource on the server is
> denied!</p> </div></div></body></html> has been rebuilt successfully
> in 00:00:17 Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in
> 00:00:16
```

I tried

```
bin/magento indexer:reset
```

If I run the reindex from the admin it works but I need to run it from the console after I import products.

Any help welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this on one of my sites before, It turned out to simply be a rule in my .htaccess file was blocking access.

After swapping back to the standard htaccess file from the [Magento github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magento/magento2/2.3/.htaccess) the issue was resolved.